# Delete Objects in Bucket with jQuery

Tags: autodesk-forge

How do i selete an object in a bucket through a jQuery-Call. The following Code shows my example for uploading the file. The goal is to have the deleting in a similar way. Thanks

```
function uploadFile(node) {
$('#hiddenUploadField').click();
$('#hiddenUploadField').change(function () {
  if (this.files.length == 0) return;
  var file = this.files[0];
  switch (node.type) {
  case 'bucket':
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileToUpload', file);
    formData.append('bucketKey', node.id);

    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/forge/oss/objects',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (data) {
        $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).refresh_node(node);
      }
    });
    break;
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could expose the necessary part on the server side (just like it is done for the **/api/forge/oss/objects** endpoint which uploads a file to a given bucket) which then could be called from the client side in a similar way.

**Server side**:

```js
router.delete('/buckets/:id', function (req, res) {
    var tokenSession = new token(req.session)

    var id = req.params.id

    var buckets = new forgeSDK.BucketsApi();
    buckets.deleteBucket(id, tokenSession.getOAuth(), tokenSession.getCredentials())
      .then(function (data) {
          res.json({ status: "success" })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          res.status(error.statusCode).end(error.statusMessage);
      })
})
```

**Client side**:

```js
function deleteBucket(id) {
    console.log("Delete bucket = " + id);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dm/buckets/' + encodeURIComponent(id),
        type: 'DELETE'
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.status === 'success') {
            $('#forgeFiles').jstree(true).refresh()
            showProgress("Bucket deleted", "success")
        }
    }).fail(function(err) {
        console.log('DELETE /dm/buckets/ call failed\n' + err.statusText);
    });
}
```

Have a look at this sample which has both file upload and bucket deletion implemented: https://github.com/adamenagy/oss.manager-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Ah great, thank you. And how would you solve it on the server side with C# ? Rigth now the Upload on server-side looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/forge/oss/objects")]
public async Task<dynamic> UploadObject()
{
  // basic input validation
  HttpRequest req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(req.Params["bucketKey"]))
    throw new System.Exception("BucketKey parameter was not provided.");

  if (req.Files.Count != 1)
    throw new System.Exception("Missing file to upload");

  string bucketKey = req.Params["bucketKey"];
  HttpPostedFile file = req.Files[0];

  // save the file on the server
  var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), 
  file.FileName);
  file.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

  // get the bucket...
  dynamic oauth = await OAuthController.GetInternalAsync();
  ObjectsApi objects = new ObjectsApi();
  objects.Configuration.AccessToken = oauth.access_token;

  // upload the file/object, which will create a new object
  dynamic uploadedObj;
  using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileSavePath))
  {
    uploadedObj = await objects.UploadObjectAsync(bucketKey,file.FileName, 
  (int)streamReader.BaseStream.Length, streamReader.BaseStream,"application/octet- 
   stream");
  }

  // cleanup
  File.Delete(fileSavePath);

  return uploadedObj;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this sample which should have all the necessary code: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bucket.manager-csharp-sample.tool